# How to make a Floating website chat button translation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Good day! I'm trying to make a copy the style of Floating Website Chat Button that when a user clicks on the large button the button will disappear it will show some inputs transform into a chat box like something like this https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/VPJpaW

Here's the fiddle of https://jsfiddle.net/Lkagowe7/ that has what I've tried so far. I also wanted it to spin around the bottom so I used this other thread.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Web Chat Widget v4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: none" class="form-box " id="myDIV">
            <h2 class="login-header"><i class="far fa-comment-dots icon"></i>We'll text you.</h2>
            <div class="test">
                <form class="formInput">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" required id="test">
                        <label class="inputLabel">Name</label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="numberText" required>
                        <label class="inputLabel">Mobile No.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"  required>
                        <label class="inputLabel">Message</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" id="inputFile" required><label id="labelFile" for="inputFile">
                    <i class="far fa-file-image" id="iconPhoto"></i>Choose a Photo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="legal">By submitting you agree to receive text messages
            at the number provided. Message/data rates apply</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitButt" class="active">
        </form>
        <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="icons">
                <button class="floating-btn" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#submitButt').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#test").focus();
        });
        document.querySelector('.floating-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.target.closest('button').classList.toggle('clicked');
        });

        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
          if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("test").focus();

          }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Graphik,avenir next,avenir,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="file"]{
  display: none;
}

.floating-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f5af09;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-out, box-shadow 0.25s ease-out;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.floating-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}


.floating-btn.clicked {
  background-color: #4169cc;
}

.floating-btn i {
  transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.floating-btn.clicked i {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

#labelFile{
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #f5af09;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#legal{
  margin: 16px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-width: 25em;
  line-height: 1.0;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
}

#inputFile{
  border: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon{
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 21px;
}

#iconPhoto{
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.form-box {
  margin: 16px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 340px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f5f5f7;
}

.test{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 27px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-right: 37px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;

}

.login-header {
  border-top-left-radius: 9px;
  border-top-right-radius: 9px;
  background: #4169cc;
  padding: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-box input{
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.form-box textarea{
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-box input,.form-box textarea{
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  cursor: text;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  transition: .3s width ease-in-out;
  margin: none;

}

.form-box input[type="submit"]{
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4169cc;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.form-box form div{
  position: relative;
}

#submitButt{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 121px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 10;
}

.active{
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

.form-box form div .inputLabel{
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form-box input:focus ~ .inputLabel,
.form-box textarea:focus ~ .inputLabel,
.form-box input:valid ~ .inputLabel,
.form-box textarea:valid ~ .inputLabel{
  top: -12px;
  left: 0;
  color: #4169cc;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.form-box input:focus,
.form-box textarea:focus,
.form-box textarea:valid,
.form-box input:valid{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(76, 118, 224);
}

.footer{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  min-height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Sounds fine. What does all that code do, and what are you asking for?

Comment: Hey Nico, I want to make the button goes translate like this https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/VPJpaW , that is when the user clicks the button it will disappear and the input will show..

Comment: help me @NicoHaase pleaseee...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [one](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/e06hcazq/8/) way of doing it. I've modified your fiddle to get it working. It's not exactly as the example, but it does show how you can animate your chat box in and out.

You can't really animate things if your are using the `display` css property to hide and show. So you need to use things like opacity and height and width to shrink and hide and show.

```
.form-box {
  margin: 16px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f5f5f7;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.form-box.open {
  transform: translate(10px, -70px);
  height: 490px;
  width: 366px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

If you're not using styles to hide and show, you need to apply a class, so here is the change I made to your `myFunction` function to get that working:

```
if (x.classList.contains('open')) {
  x.classList.remove("open");
 } else {
  x.classList.add("open");
  document.getElementById("test").focus();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir :) I really appreciate it